# '"./testing"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c, ide, geany

so I'm trying to run a c program on a compiler called geany but keep running on to this error whenever I try and run the program. I know there isn't any mistake on the actual code as I am able to compile it. I am also able to run it on online IDE's. It just will not run on an IDE on my computer. I've tried visual studio, and another third party ide and I am still getting a similar error.

Comment: Did you tried to run it in a terminal?

Comment: Did you recompile on your computer or just copy the compiled binary from another machine? It would be good if you could clarify the operating system you are using and check that the file is marked as executable.

Comment: There's not enough information here. *I am able to compile it* pretty much means there weren't any syntax errors. Did you link it after compiling? Is there an actual executable file named *testing* in the directory? Did you compile and link on this computer, or somewhere else and then copy the binary? *I can run it on online IDEs* has no bearing on anything here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing enough information to let us help you. Don't add comments nor answers, this is *not* a forum. -- BTW, Geany (if you use the same like me) is *not* a compiler, it is an enhanced editor that knows a bit about compiling, linking and running programs.